# Jquery Accordion & Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, accordion

am trying to use the [Jquery accordion](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion#options) to show a list of  links generated by wordpress with the [`wp_list_categories();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) function.

This function returns a list of `<ul>` `<li>` `<a>` tags. My problem is that in order to get it working fine, like the second exemple on [this page](http://jquery.bassistance.de/accordion/demo/), the heading `<a>` tags, have to get a special class: `<a class="head" href="?p=1.1.1">Guitar</a>` that is used in the js definition of the accordion:

```
jQuery('#navigation').accordion({
        active: false,
        autoheight:false,
        header: '.head',
        event: 'mouseover'
    });
```

Without this class, the hover opens the sub list, but as soon as i get down to hover on of the child elements, it closes the accordion. The exemple is the grey bloc on [this page](http://soulbrasileiro.com.br/site/).

My question goes like this, is it possible to append with javascript the required class (.head for ex) to this dynamically generated list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is, especially since you're using jQuery.

```
jQuery('#navigation > li > a').addClass('head');
```

It's not beautiful, but it should work. Add it in before the code you quoted.

Comment: Yep that works just fine. Am pretty new to jQuery so i'll write this down as it could be helpfull in the future.

Comment: But have you tried Alex' answer? It is faster and avoids the `head` class altogether, so if you can go without it...

Comment: As i wrote down, yes i did try Alex's solution first. But there was the opening problem.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting header to `.head`, could you set it to `#navigation > li > a`, which would select the top level `<a>` tags?

Comment: +1 after checking docs @Kevin: try this first, and if it doesn't work, use my answer. My answer does apply the `head` class which beautifies the headers, but some CSS changes should do it with this answer too.

Comment: I tried your solution Alex first, was working but the only thing is that my accordion was starting all open and css style wasnt applied, but this was secundary. Thanks all lot anyway guys!